# User Control on Panel remains visible when visible set to false

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I am trying to swap out user controls dynamically. How can I 'hide' controls on a panel? Removing them from the Controls collection does not work and setting the control's visible property does not work.

```
ServersView servers = new ServersView();           
       ServersPresenter presenter = new ServersPresenter(servers);
       _view.SettingsPanel.Controls.Add(servers);
       _view.SettingsPanel.Controls[0].Visible = false;
```

The new control is not visible after added because the other user control is still visible. Can someone tell me how to hide the user controls?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that the control you're adding is the first in the SettingsPannel.Controls collection? If there's another control in there, you will add yours and set the first one's visible property!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check to make sure that controls[0] is the really the control you think it is. For example, is servers the same object as _view.SettingsPanel.Controls[0]? Would it be better to add all the controls once, maybe at form load or some early time, then set the visible property later? That way, you don't have to worry about adding too many controls later on.

Comment: Yes.. I was accidentally adding the same control more than once.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the control collection is empty at the moment you add a new item? When you add an item, it is placed at the end of the collection, so it's better to refer the last item.

Try to get index of the control in the collection:

```
int index = _view.SettingsPanel.Controls.GetChildIndex(servers);
_view.SettingsPanel.Controls[index].Visible = false;
```

IMHO.